# Error slashes in tag a link

Tags: php, html

I have a line code:

```
array('<a href=\'search.php?keyword="'.$k['words'].'"\'>'.$k['words'].'</a>' => 'left');
```

If k['words'] = "a word's"; it will error:

```html
<a href="search.php?keyword=&quot;a word" s"'="">a word's</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

escaping is key. urlencode for urls, htmlspecialchars for everything else.

```
array('<a href="search.php?keyword='.
   urlencode($k['words']).'">'.
   htmlspecialchars($k['words']).'</a>' => 'left');
```